# Extract IPA i am accessing sqlite file and Audio files in resource folder

Tags: ios, ios4

I am saving ipa file to.zip and when extracting the zip, I am getting application file, in which I am seeing all resource files. How can I make this it all secure?

Some of my friends are telling me, that someone can crack IPA and distribute it through torrents.

The code looks like the one below. Can any body help me out ?

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSDictionary *info = [bundle infoDictionary];
if ([info objectForKey: @"SignerIdentity"] != nil)
{
/* do something */
}
```